# JavaScript, what is set for "length" in the following function, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this function using code on internet.

It works.

But why .length in the for loop statement ?

Length mean something you can measure how long it is, no ?

It's a bit Like the word width, no ?

So, why measuring a radio button length to know if it exist ?
What kind of length it is ?

```
function monte(fichier_c)
    {
    var boutonRadio = document.getElementsByName("id_ordre_transport");
    var monte = "rien";

    for (var i = 0; i < boutonRadio.length; i++)
        {
        if (boutonRadio[i].checked)
            {
            //alert(fichier_c);
            //alert(boutonRadio[i].value);
            //alert( "#monte"+boutonRadio[i].value);
            var monte = fichier_c+"#monte"+boutonRadio[i].value;
            }
        }
    if ( monte == "rien" )
        {
        //alert(fichier_c);
        var monte = fichier_c;
        }

        return monte;
        }
```

Can someone explain me what this length is set for ?

Comment: document.getElementsByName("id_ordre_transport") returns an array of items. length is a property of an array: the number of items in it. boutonRadio.length is not "set", it's for reading.

Comment: Can you link the places on the internet from where you gathered your codes?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot link places, they are to many places, I took a bit of each and spent a day to merge them and write this function, I'm a very beginner with JS.

Comment: Chris, I understood it was for readind, but in PHP (wich I know better), I wouldn't measure a length of an array, to know if indexes are set. I would rather count them, or test if empty or exist, this way look very amazing for me, I would find something like count than length, well it's JS.

Comment: How can I set this question to solved ?

Comment: Bergi, At least, this one set me on the good way, go to tag #3 (on right side of date answers) http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?679670-RESOLVED-How-to-use-Javascript-to-get-the-value-of-a-radio-button&s=381b17ed3ae62e8f44fe8e0ff246e990&p=4172322&viewfull=1#post4172322. that one helped me as well http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Ok, I've bookmarked MDN. (And looking for accepting an answer ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript: `document.getElementsByName("id_ordre_transport");` represent all element(array of element) with name "id_ordre_transport". in a html page it may have many radio button. `boutonRadio.length` represent number of radio button with name "id_ordre_transport".

```
for (var i = 0; i < boutonRadio.length; i++)
    {
    if (boutonRadio[i].checked)
        {
        //alert(fichier_c);
        //alert(boutonRadio[i].value);
        //alert( "#monte"+boutonRadio[i].value);
        var monte = fichier_c+"#monte"+boutonRadio[i].value;
        }
 }
```

above code loop through all element and checked if radio button is checked or unchecked
using `boutonRadio[i].checked` if checked then it assign some value on `monte` variable

**Good and short answer (as a comment above) :
length is a property of array. it measure the array length. ex: var a=[1,2,3] it means array "a" has length 3 –  Mukund Kumar 18 hours ago**

Comment: Do you mean .length measure the width of the value "id_ordre_transport" ?, and if the length is not set to zero, then it exist ?

Comment: length is a property of array. it measure the array length.

ex: var a=[1,2,3]
it means array "a" has length 3

Answer (score 1):

> But why .length in the for loop statement?

The variable name `boutonRadio` is chosen unfortunate - it is not a single button.

> Length mean something you can measure how long it is, no ?

Yes.

> So, why measuring a radio button length to know if it exist ?

Kinda. But as said, it's not the length of a single radio button.

> What kind of length it is ?

The [`document.getElementsByName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) does return a [collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of all elements with that name - which might be one, but might also be none or multiple ones.

This collection, an array-like object, is what we iterate by the loop; executing our code for each index from `0` to its `.length`. The single radio buttons are each referred by as `boutonRadio[i]` in the loop body.

Comment: Do you mean .length is the width of the content of boutonRadio[i] ?

Comment: No, the `.length` is the number of the elements in the collection, it's the length of the list.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thanks. A bit amazing (for me), but ok, I record this information as it is.